# Chroma.from_documents Segmentation Fault

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, chromadb

I am a new user of Chroma and I have some difficulties concerning Chroma.from_documents.

I have a simple code running:

```
def loader(link):
    loader = WebBaseLoader(link)
    data = loader.load()
    return data

def splitter(data):
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1500, chunk_overlap=100)
    all_splits = text_splitter.split_documents(data)
    return all_splits

def vector_storage(all_splits, name):
    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=all_splits,
                                    embedding=GPT4AllEmbeddings(), 
                                    persist_directory="./chroma_data/"+name)
    return vectorstore

QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = hub.pull("rlm/rag-prompt-llama")
llm = load_llm()

for i in df["websites"]:
 

    try:
        data = loader(i)
        all_splits = splitter(data)
        vectorstore = vector_storage(all_splits, i)
        #question = "Can you give me a summary of this webpage"# the field of this company"
        docs = vectorstore.similarity_search(question)
        qa_chain = get_qa_chain(llm, QA_CHAIN_PROMPT, vectorstore)
        result = qa_chain({"query": question})
        print(result)
    except:
        print(i + "   not working")
```

It works quite well but after a couple of iteration I got a segmentaion fault.

I saw this in the documentation of Chroma:

> Caution: Chroma makes a best-effort to automatically save data to
> disk, however multiple in-memory clients can stomp each other’s work.
> As a best practice, only have one client per path running at any given
> time.

However I am not quite sure what is wrong? Should I not use the Chroma.from_documents this way?
Should I create first a collection of all documents and then ask in the for loop to check specifically to certain documents? Any other recommandations?

Thank you for your help !

Best,